# How to embed seekbar inside a video using ffmpeg?

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

how to embed seekbar inside a video using `node-fluent-ffmpeg`.

Ex:-

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Script:**

Here's a working script that draws a 20px dark-red progress bar on the bottom of the video using only node's `fluent-ffmpeg`. It requires a recent version of `ffmpeg` installed to work (I used 4.0.2). You can change the bar color from `DarkRed` to [any valid `ffmpeg` color](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#color-syntax), and change the height by setting `bar_height` to the desire value in pixels.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');

let bar_height = 20;
let input_file = 'input_file.mp4';
let output_file = 'output_file.mp4';
ffmpeg.ffprobe(input_file, (err, data) => {
    let input_duration = data.format.duration;
    let progressBarGraph = [
        {
          inputs: '0',
          filter: 'drawbox',
          options: {
              h: 'iw',
              c: 'DarkRed',
              width: 'iw',
              thickness: 'fill'
          },
          outputs: 'rectangle'
        },
        {
            inputs: ['0', 'rectangle'],
            filter: 'overlay',
            options: {
                x: `-W+W*(t/${input_duration})`,
                y: `H-${bar_height}`
            },
            outputs: "output"
        }
    ];

    ffmpeg(input_file).complexFilter(progressBarGraph, "output").output(output_file).run();
});
```

**Sample Output:**

Here's a screenshot of the output on a video file:

[image: Red bar on bottom of video from Rogue One trailer]

Comment: Can you also demonstrate how to add an icon ahead of seekbar so it moves along with seekbar?

Comment: And what if I want to show this seekbar at top of the video?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a library like [flowplayer](https://flowplayer.com/) as suggested in the [documentation](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg#usage).

Also, after looking at the options provided by the plugin, you can write your own seekbar, you will need to follow these steps when the video is loaded to calculate it:

1. Get video duration
2. Get video dimensions (specifically width for the seekbar)
3. You need to map your the width of the seekbar with the duration of the video, and set minimum and maximum limits
4. For the seekbar, you need two rectangles of the same size; however one has full width and the other zero
5. Set an interval to add every second to the result of the mapping of the width and duration of the video
6. Detect an onclick / drag event for your seekbar, and update the corresponding width of the red rectangle, and navigate with [seek option](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg#seektime-seek-output) in your video